# Using jQuery I need to print this JS object to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display a list of states separated by region on a webpage.

I need to display the Title of the Region "West" followed by the states being displayed as an `<ul>`.

I am sure there are many ways to achieve this however I must use jQuery.

```
var states = {  
  "West":[
    "Alaska",
    "Arizona",
    "California",
    "Hawaii",
    "Idaho",
    "Nevada",
    "Oregon",
    "Utah",
    "Washington"
  ],
  "Central":[
    "Colorado",
    "Illinois",
    "Indiana",
    "Iowa",
    "Kansas",
    "Michigan",
    "Minnesota",
    "Missouri",
    "Montana",
    "Nebraska",
    "New Mexico",
    "North Dakota",
    "Ohio",
    "Oklahoma",
    "South Dakota",
    "Texas",
    "Wisconsin",
    "Wyoming"
  ],
  "East":[
    "Connecticut",
    "Delaware",
    "Kentucky",
    "Maine",
    "Maryland",
    "Massachusetts",
    "New Hampshire",
    "New Jersey",
    "New York",
    "Pennsylvania",
    "Rhode Island",
    "Vermont",
    "Virginia",
    "West Virginia"
  ],
  "South":[
    "Alabama",
    "Arkansas",
    "Florida",
    "Georgia",
    "Louisiana",
    "Mississippi",
    "North Carolina",
    "South Carolina",
    "Tennessee"
  ]
};
```

this is what I have going so far:

```
var states = window.states;                                                         
var west = $.parseJSON( states ).West;

var $table = $('<table></table>');

for ( var i = 0; i < west.length; i++ ) {
    var $line = $( "<tr></tr>" );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( west ) );
    $table.append( $line );`
}

$table.appendTo( '.west' );
```

Comment: Why do you have to use jQuery?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: `var states = window.states;                                                         var west = $.parseJSON( states ).West;
    
    var $table = $('<table></table>');
    
for ( var i = 0; i < west.length; i++ ) {
    var $line = $( "<tr></tr>" );
    $line.append( $( "<td></td>" ).html( west ) );
    $table.append( $line );
}

$table.appendTo( '.west' );`

Comment: I am using a platform that requires jQuery

Comment: How to print the JS object to my page using jQuery

Comment: @CorralesD put your attempt in your question, and you realize your attempt is seems to try and put it in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `for` loop. For example, to display the states in each region,

```js
var states = {  
  "West":[
    "Alaska",
    "Arizona",
    "California",
    "Hawaii",
    "Idaho",
    "Nevada",
    "Oregon",
    "Utah",
    "Washington"
  ],
  "Central":[
    "Colorado",
    "Illinois",
    "Indiana",
    "Iowa",
    "Kansas",
    "Michigan",
    "Minnesota",
    "Missouri",
    "Montana",
    "Nebraska",
    "New Mexico",
    "North Dakota",
    "Ohio",
    "Oklahoma",
    "South Dakota",
    "Texas",
    "Wisconsin",
    "Wyoming"
  ],
  "East":[
    "Connecticut",
    "Delaware",
    "Kentucky",
    "Maine",
    "Maryland",
    "Massachusetts",
    "New Hampshire",
    "New Jersey",
    "New York",
    "Pennsylvania",
    "Rhode Island",
    "Vermont",
    "Virginia",
    "West Virginia"
  ],
  "South":[
    "Alabama",
    "Arkansas",
    "Florida",
    "Georgia",
    "Louisiana",
    "Mississippi",
    "North Carolina",
    "South Carolina",
    "Tennessee"
  ]
};
var html = "<p>States by region</p>";
for (var region in states) {
  html += "<ul>States in the " + region + " region: ";
  for (var state in states[region]) {
    html += "<li>" + states[region][state] + "</li>";
  }
  html += "</ul>";
}
$('#states').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="states">

</div>
```

This code allows you to iterate through each region and its children without knowing what each region is defined as.

## Edits

- Changed to iterate through entire states object

Comment: states is an object.  Not an array.  You just need `states.West`.

Comment: @VtoCorleone Correct, states is an Object, but it's child ('West') is an array, so you must iterate through it as such.

Comment: @VtoCorleone , My last comment was misleading. It's not that its child ('West') is an array, but instead it is not an Object, therefore there is no such thing as states.West. In order to access it, it must be through states['West'].

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var states = {
                "West": [
                  "Alaska",
                  "Arizona",
                  "California",
                  "Hawaii",
                  "Idaho",
                  "Nevada",
                  "Oregon",
                  "Utah",
                  "Washington"
                ],
                "Central": [
                  "Colorado",
                  "Illinois",
                  "Indiana",
                  "Iowa",
                  "Kansas",
                  "Michigan",
                  "Minnesota",
                  "Missouri",
                  "Montana",
                  "Nebraska",
                  "New Mexico",
                  "North Dakota",
                  "Ohio",
                  "Oklahoma",
                  "South Dakota",
                  "Texas",
                  "Wisconsin",
                  "Wyoming"
                ],
                "East": [
                  "Connecticut",
                  "Delaware",
                  "Kentucky",
                  "Maine",
                  "Maryland",
                  "Massachusetts",
                  "New Hampshire",
                  "New Jersey",
                  "New York",
                  "Pennsylvania",
                  "Rhode Island",
                  "Vermont",
                  "Virginia",
                  "West Virginia"
                ],
                "South": [
                  "Alabama",
                  "Arkansas",
                  "Florida",
                  "Georgia",
                  "Louisiana",
                  "Mississippi",
                  "North Carolina",
                  "South Carolina",
                  "Tennessee"
                ]
            };
            var west = states.West;
            var $table = $('<table></table>');
            for (var i = 0; i < west.length; i++) {
                var $line = $("<tr></tr>");
                $line.append($("<td></td>").html(west[i]));
                $table.append($line);
            }
            $table.appendTo('.west');
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="west"></div>
</body>
</html>
```